# Why below query not giving proper output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table `topic` and `question_set`. I want to show top 3 question from each topic, I have written the query but, it's not generating rank, It's giving same rank for each row.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS (   
 SELECT A.ID, B.topic_name 
    FROM question_sets A 
    INNER JOIN topics B 
    ON A.topic_id = B.Id 
    WHERE  test_section_id = 3 
    AND exam_category_id = 2 
    ORDER BY appeared 
 );

SELECT ID,topic_name , 
       @rank := IF(@topic = topic_name, @rank + 1, 1) AS ranking,
       @topic := topic_name 
FROM temp_table
ORDER BY topic_name DESC
```

Comment: You are creating table with name `TEMPORARY ` and retrieving data from `temp_table` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more recent versions of MySQL, you need to sort the data in a subquery before using variables.  And, you should not assign a variable in one expression and use it in another.

So:

```
SELECT ID,topic_name , 
       (@rank := IF(@topic = topic_name, @rank + 1,
                    IF(@topic := topic_name, 1, 1)
                   )
       ) as ranking
FROM (SELECT tt.*
      FROM temp_table tt
      ORDER BY topic_name DESC
     ) tt CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @topic := '', @rank := 0) params;
```

You probably want a second key after the `topic_name DESC` if you actually want to rank by some column.  You cannot depend on the ordering in the temporary table -- because tables represent *unordered* sets.

In MySQL 8+, you would simply do:

```
select tt.*,
       row_number() over (partition by topic_name order by ?) as seqnum
from temp_table tt;
```

Comment: thank you, I was using one variable in another expression that why I'm getting same row number. In above code I have added another nested query to sort the row by topic_name as it's not generating row number properly.

Comment: DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS ( 
 SELECT ID,topic_name
     FROM
     (
 SELECT A.ID, B.topic_name
    FROM question_sets A 
    INNER JOIN topics B 
    ON A.topic_id = B.Id 
    WHERE
    test_section_id = 3 
    AND exam_category_id = 2 
    ORDER BY appeared ) A ORDER BY topic_name  
 );